# Как продолжить записывать видео с помощю OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, видео

Нужно каждые 5 секунд обновлять записанные мной файл output.avi, но к сожалению при открытие потока записи заново, она стирает предыдущие кадры. Как это исправить?

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("Road traffic video for object recognition.mp4")
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', 0x7634706d, 20.0, (1280,720))

counter = 0
while(cap.isOpened()):
ret, frame = cap.read()
if not (out.isOpened()):
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', 0x7634706d, 20.0, (1280, 720))

if ret==True:
    # write the flipped frame
    out.write(frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    if counter % 100:
        out.release()
    counter += 1
else:
    break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: В англоязычном so говорят что никак, склеивайте ffmpeg ом https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194902/opencv-append-frame-to-existing-video-avi-file